# Laravel - Websocket between two separate laravel projects

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io

How can I make WebSocket between two laravel projects and connect them?

In other words, I need two laravel projects which one of them is a WebSocket server and another is a WebSocket client !! and I use from socket.io.

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can advise me!

Comment: Have you looked into laravel echo at all.

Comment: @MichaelMano - yes, but is it possible to get data from **laravel echo** which installed on one of them? this point is important which I have two separate projects!

Comment: Yes, Laravel echo works on separate frontend and domains, Ive even set it up running on a mobile application before.

Comment: @MichaelMano - Actually I need to run a socket server, I haven't any problem with the socket client.

Comment: @MichaelMano can you please show me how you got it setup to work, i've been at it for weeks now and i can't figure a thing out

Comment: @TheGripVic First off have you got it set up to work on one server? e.g a base laravel install?

Comment: @MichaelMano I already have it setup on one server. So I tried creating another laravel project that'll act as the client. But the Laravel echo doesn't subscribe or listen to the channel I have on the main server

Comment: This is hard to debug here. Unless you create your own question. Does your `laravel-echo-server.json` have `"apiOriginAllow": {
  "allowCors": true,
  "allowOrigin": "*",
  "allowMethods": "GET",
  "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
 }`

Comment: I don't have a laravel-echo-server.json file. I'll create a question then